# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am new to rails and doing a project with the help of Michael Hartl'  tutorial of rails 4 http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#sec-following_and_followers_pages
while creating a form for following users it's showing 
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty in rails 4

```
    <%= form_for(current_user.relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user.id)) do |f| %>
    <div>
    <%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Follow", class:"btn btn-large" %>
    <% end %>
```

relationships_controller.rb

```
    def create
      @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
      current_user.follow!(@user)
      redirect_to @user
    end
```

Can you please give me solution to avoid this error? while i am inserting data in relationships table via rails console. it's ok. but it cant create any new object from form and showing this error.

Solution . if i change the first argument like follwing then its working but does not getting the unfollow button

```
        <%= form_for(Relationship.new(followed_id: @user.id)) do |f|  %>
```

Comment: I am not able to understand, what you are trying to do?

Comment: thanks guys for your support all is well now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hartl's tutorial its not working, but found a solution, its simple, While i am checking if the cuurent_user is following user or not? if not then partial will throw me to follow page.where if create the form with
        <%= form_for(Relationship.new(followed_id: @user.id))%>
i can create following users

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because, the current_user is not following @user and there is no relationship between them, thus **current_user.relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user.id)** returns nil as a parameter to the form.

Refer Michael Hartl's tutorial properly, you will see

`_follow_form.html.erb`

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
  <div id="follow_form">
  <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
    <%= render 'unfollow' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'follow' %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

There are two partials to show the follow form button,

1) When the user is following another user/page there is `_unfollow.html.erb` partial

`_unfollow.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user),
             html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-large" %>
<% end %>
```

2) When the user is not following another user there is `_follow.html.erb` partial

`_follow.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: i followed his tutorial properly but cant get rid of this error. thanks for your comment

Comment: Ah! I think you din understand the point here, you will get *nil* when you try to find a relation that does not exists. That is why you will check with current_user.following(@user)?, only if it is true you will invoke the corresponding relation, if it is false you will show another form that is used to form a relation.

And if you follow the tutorial properly you will not get the error. Please check again.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty in rails 4.

This means that in

```
form_for(current_user.relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user.id))
```

`current_user.relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user.id)` returned nil. In other words, of the current user's relationships, none of them had `followed_id == @user.id`.

To fix this, try to figure out why you are searching for the given `@user.id`, and why you expect the relationship to exist.

#### Update

Since you are trying to create a new relationship, you can use

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id)) do |f| %>
```

instead. `find_*` tries to find an existing record in the DB, whereas `build` makes a record in memory with the given attributes (*i.e.* not saved to DB yet.)

Comment: i dont expect the relationship to exist where i want to make realtionship with follow. and @user.id is others id than current_user who is going to follow the other user.

Comment: @user.id is nil but why. this form is showing in user's show page. and in users controller show action it is declared

Comment: thanks for your valuable comment. I figured out that there is no relationship exists for that it showing this error. In this case what should i do to make a relation by follow button?