# Rails 4: ArgumentError in Models#edit - First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

First, please let me state that I know similar questions have already been asked and I checked them out:

- [Form_for "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15379495/form-for-first-argument-in-form-cannot-contain-nil-or-be-empty-error)
- [ror4 First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809889/ror4-first-argument-in-form-cannot-contain-nil-or-be-empty)
- [First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty - user sign up form - rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974148/first-argument-in-form-cannot-contain-nil-or-be-empty-user-sign-up-form-rail)
- [First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty in rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057854/first-argument-in-form-cannot-contain-nil-or-be-empty-in-rails-4)
- [Rails 4: Receiving the following error: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018830/rails-4-receiving-the-following-error-first-argument-in-form-cannot-contain-ni)

Unfortunately, none of them helped me figure out a solution to my issue.

I am following Jessica Biggs's *[Creating a Scoped Invitation System for Rails](https://coderwall.com/p/rqjjca/creating-a-scoped-invitation-system-for-rails)* codewall.com tutorial.

Where the author uses the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Association
   has_many :memberships
   has_many :user_groups, through: :memberships
   has_many :invitations, :class_name => "Invite", :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
   has_many :sent_invites, :class_name => "Invite", :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
end

class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Association #(Could be a company, club, circle, etc.)
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :users, through: :memberships
    has_many :invites 
end

class Membership <  ActiveRecord::Association #(Pass through model)
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :user_group
end

class Invite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_group
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

I am using these models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
  has_many :invitations, :class_name => "Invite", :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
  has_many :sent_invites, :class_name => "Invite", :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
  has_many :invites
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Invite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

To make things clearer, here is a correspondance between Jessica's models and mine:

- User <=> User
- UserGroup <=> Calendar
- Membership <=> Administration

Fast forward to *Send Invitation Form* section, where the tutorial recommends to include the following form:

```
<%= form_for @invite , :url => invites_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_group_id, :value => @invite.user_group_id %>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
    <%= f.submit 'Send' %>
<% end %>
```

into what would be in my app the Calendars Edit view.

Of course, I have replaced every occurrence of `user_group` with `calendar`.

The problem is that now, when I go to this particular view — which used to work — I am now getting the following error:

```
ArgumentError in Calendars#edit
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

I understand that I need to define @invite in Calendars#Edit but I don't know how.

I tried `@invite = Calendar.invites.new` and `@invite = User.invites.new` but none of those worked.

Any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you actually need the desired record @calendar or @user, for initializing its associated records

```
@calendar = Calendar.find(params[:id])
@invite = @calendar.invites.build
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Unless I made a mistake, it seems I still get the same error.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just updated the question with the relationship association between Invite the other models.

Comment: And you need to define relationship for invites in Calendar model too

Comment: in fact, both in Calendar and User.. you need to define `has_many: invites`

Comment: Sorry, I had not completely updated my question. Now, you can see how User and Calendar relate to Invite.

Comment: Yes, it does! Thank you very much.